# group ids some common some dissimilar R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, case, mutate

I want to make an ID for group members that is sometimes common and sometimes dissimilar. I have a few cases where dissimilarity is needed, so I can specify those manually in the code or as a list.

Imagine data like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group3", "Group3", "Group4", "Group4", "Group4"),
  Member = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve", "Frank", "Grace", "Helen", "Ivy", "John")
)
```

Basically, I want something where, say, Group 1 has a common ID so Alice = 1, Bob = 1, but then group 2 has globally unique IDs that vary within the group, so Charlie =2, David = 3, and Eve = 4, but then we switch back to similar for Group 3.

Final ideal data would hypothetically look like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group3", "Group3", "Group4", "Group4", "Group4"),
  Member = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve", "Frank", "Grace", "Helen", "Ivy", "John"),
ID = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6)
)
```

I am most familiar with dplyr, and so have been experimenting with

```
Data %>%
group_by(Group)%>%
mutate(ID = row_number())
```

And variations thereof including case_when and ifelse statements.

Ideal outcome would be code that uses case_when or ifelse in the mutate to let me specify n groups that should have different within group IDs and let something like the TRUE~ portion of the case when assign globally unique common IDs to the rest of the groups.

Comment: Your sample data is broken, lengths 10, 10, and 8.

Comment: You have `ID=5` shared across `Group3` and `Group4`, are we supposed to ignore the `Group` column?

Comment: My apologies I edit it now. I do want most groups except for a few to have a common ID for all members, as would normally be the case with group based IDs. But there are a few where the grouping variable is a more generic label - like Cars versus the type of car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this would suit your use-case?

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

data <- data.frame(
  Group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group3", "Group3", "Group4", "Group4", "Group4"),
  Member = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve", "Frank", "Grace", "Helen", "Ivy", "John")
)

data %>%
  mutate(Group_number = row_number(), .by = Group) %>%
  mutate(tmp = case_when(Group == "Group2" ~ 1,
                         Group == "Group4" ~ 1,
                         Group_number == 1 ~ 1,
                         TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(ID = cumsum(tmp)) %>%
  select(-c(Group_number, tmp))
#>     Group  Member ID
#> 1  Group1   Alice  1
#> 2  Group1     Bob  1
#> 3  Group2 Charlie  2
#> 4  Group2   David  3
#> 5  Group2     Eve  4
#> 6  Group3   Frank  5
#> 7  Group3   Grace  5
#> 8  Group4   Helen  6
#> 9  Group4     Ivy  7
#> 10 Group4    John  8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

EDIT: based on the comment below, only Group2 should be 'dissimilar':

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

data <- data.frame(
  Group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group3", "Group3", "Group4", "Group4", "Group4"),
  Member = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve", "Frank", "Grace", "Helen", "Ivy", "John")
)

data %>%
  mutate(Group_number = row_number(), .by = Group) %>%
  mutate(tmp = case_when(Group == "Group2" ~ 1,
                        # Group == "Group4" ~ 1,
                         Group_number == 1 ~ 1,
                         TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(ID = cumsum(tmp)) %>%
  select(-c(Group_number, tmp))
#>     Group  Member ID
#> 1  Group1   Alice  1
#> 2  Group1     Bob  1
#> 3  Group2 Charlie  2
#> 4  Group2   David  3
#> 5  Group2     Eve  4
#> 6  Group3   Frank  5
#> 7  Group3   Grace  5
#> 8  Group4   Helen  6
#> 9  Group4     Ivy  6
#> 10 Group4    John  6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is close but all of group 4 should have a common ID unless otherwise specified.

Comment: I believe I've fixed it @Grum; please let me know if I've misunderstood

Comment: this works very well and scales nicely to a larger dataset. It is also not prone to breaking with the addition of new data/Groups, since you are specifying the groups that should be dissimilar despite a common group id

Comment: Thanks @Grum; glad you solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

```
# set the ones you want to be different, and then set their names to be the groups in the Group column
different = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) |> setNames(unique(data$Group))

# find rows which are part of a Group where different = TRUE or alternatively, ones where a new group has been started
data |> mutate(ID = cumsum(different[Group] | Group != lag(Group, default = "")))
```

Note:
If your groups are literally the same as in the example, it's probably better to remove the "Group" part and turn them into integers

Comment: this method works, but I accepted the other as it was easier to implement in the context of my data. Having to list the various FALSE, TRUE, etc., was unwieldy at scale and prone to breaking if the data changes. But it does work!